# Getting rid of ' " ' from json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a code snippet that is encoding a PHP array into json but when i am trying to parse it it gives me error because of " present in value

PHP array

```
$arr = array( id => 1, msg => <h1>Some text</h1> <img src="http://test.png">);
```

Js code

```
var json = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($arr);?>');
```

When i json_encode the above error it surrounds string with double quotes that breaks my JSON.parse function. I tried using replace function but after json_encode it automatically adds double quotes surrounding the string values of object.

So i tried to replace all " with ' but it is replacing all double quotes. i am thinking can it be done by regex to replace only " in html elements or something else. I could not escape HTMl at time of saving because a large number of data is already present in the database and changing it is bit difficult.

Comment: `$arr = array( id => 1, msg => "<h1>Some text</h1> <img src=\"http://test.png\">")`

Comment: what do you expect. a json string **MUST** be wrapped in `"`. removing them makes it a json syntax error. changing what json_encode produced is obviously introducing syntax errors. You can NOT redefine what json should be by mangling a json string, then expecting a json parser to accept the bad text you're producing.

Comment: you don't need to do that: `var json = <?= json_encode($arr); ?>` should be enough.

Comment: Hi @Blazemonger  i can not escape double quotes in html because it is already saved in database.

Comment: json_encode() will escape double quotes with a backslash and always produces valid JSON. Maybe your decoder is broken?

Comment: @Gerry — It's being broken by having the JSON slapped into the middle of a JavaScript string literal without further escaping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON is already parsed the moment PHP does print it.

```
var json = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
```

When do you need `JSON.parse()` then?

`JSON.parse()` turns an already escaped JSON into a JSON/Javascript object.

`JSON.stringify()` does the exact opposite, escaping JSON to a string.

Answer (score 3):

When inserting JSON into JavaScript, it is not necessary to wrap it in quotes or even try to parse it, because JSON is a valid JavaScript object or array literal. By removing the quotes, you eliminate the problem of needing to escape quotes.

```
var json = <?php echo json_encode($arr);?>;
```